# Redux action doubles "on" socket events

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, socket.io

I have application written in Reactjs and Redux. With axios its is working good, but I would like to use socket.io, so in redux action in try:

```
export const getOne = (id) => async dispatch => {
  socket.emit('getOne', id);

  console.log('test');

  socket.on('get', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    dispatch({ type: GET, payload: msg });
  });
};
```

If I call this action first time everything is working good - socket is emitted, on function return me correct msg and console.log return "test", but if I call this function again, then console.log is called one (this is ok), but unfortunately the "socket.on" is called two times. Next if I click, then the "socket.on" function is called three times etc...

When I should put my function `socket.on('get', function(msg)`? Or what can I do it with this issue?

Comment: only bind it once.

Comment: How can I bind this?

Answer (score 0):

You need move "socket.on"  to out of function. Each call of this function, it bind again and again:

```
     socket.on('get', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        dispatch({ type: GET, payload: msg });
     });

    export const getOne = (id) => async dispatch => {
      socket.emit('getOne', id);
      console.log('test');
    };
```